# Nullable reference types silently fail when referencing oblivious code?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have a C# project with [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types) enabled:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- more stuff here -->
</Project>
```

I've set a couple of warnings to become errors in my .editorconfig:

```
[*.cs]

# CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8600.severity = error

# CS8603: Possible null reference return.
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8603.severity = error
```

In my project, I have a class, and the following **won't compile**, which is perfect:

```
public class NullableCompilerChecking
{
   public string WontCompile(string? input)
    => input;  // error: "possible null reference return"
}
```

Now for the problem. My project references another project called "Library". Library is null-oblivious. In Library, I have the following:

```
  public static class Strings
  {
    public static string Null => null;
  }
```

The problem is that when I reference the Strings class from my library, I lose the wonderful null-checking. For example, the following compiles and throws at runtime:

```
    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
      var myString = Strings.Null;
      var myIndex = myString.IndexOf("a");
    }
```

What I would have wanted is for Library's `string` to by default come to the null-aware code as a `string?` rather than a `string`. Can I do that?

Comment: im really failing to understand the question lol. Anyways - you do realize that string is a nullable type (since its a reference type, and they are by definition nullable) so a string can be null and so the compiler does not throw warnings or errors for a null assignment to string. The same way writing `string s = null` would still compile because its valid so there's really now way for the compiler to detect that. Thats why nullable types are marked with the `?` symbol so the compiler knows it can or cant be nullable

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, if you want new null checking on a library that does not support it, you have to create a [wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function#Adapting_class/object_interfaces) around it, with proper null awareness. For example:

```
public static class Strings
{
  public static string Null => null;
}

// In your code you will use only the wrapper
public static class StringsWrapper
{
  public static string? Null => Strings.Null;
}
```

In case you are using ReSharper, another lazy option would be to turn on [pessimistic nullability analisys](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Value_Analysis.html#modes), which gives you a warning/error, everywhere where you are using value that might be null.